# ST-LINK does not connect to the target

Tags: stm32

I have ST-LINK dongle. When I try to connect in CubeIDE with Debug icon I have an error

Error in initializing the ST-LINK device.
Reason: No device found on the target.

It happens all the time. When I use ST-LINK utility I have the same problem, but when I push down RESET switch on board I have a connection.
Pins PA13 and PA14 are not used for another purpose. The setting in ST-LINK like Core Reset or Software reset does not work.
I only have a connection when I push down Reset switch and then try to connect only in ST-Link Utility.

Where do I make mistake and what is "connect Under Reset"?

Answer (score 1):

Connect under reset means that when the debug probe connects to the target the reset line is kept active, so no user code can be executed.

I would advise to keep this always on unless you connect to the running target.

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work for me? I can not connect to device. A few minutes earlier it connects under reset but now it does not do it at all.

Comment: @slawek is it the Chinese dongle? If yes - they do not have reset line and connect under reset is not available of course

Comment: @P__J__ Chinese dongles do have a reset pin. I know this because I own a few of those. What they lack is the SWO pin which enables some additional debugging features. Actually, with some precise soldering skills you can add a SWO pin to your Chinese clone.

Comment: @Tagli I afraid you are 100% wrong. You see the RST pin but is not controlled by the firmware and "connect under reset"does not work. Connect the scope or logic analyzer and check it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJwXq.png

Comment: I guess that pin is controlled by the firmware when "hardware reset" option is selected. Because I remember using it with SW4STM32. I had to use it when "hardware reset" was selected, but it's not used when "software reset" is selected. But I don't know what "connect under reset" does.

Answer (score 0):

One thing could be that the software that is flashed onto your STM32 disables those pins and as such you can't connect debug/program it when it has booted.

Keeping the STM under reset while trying to connect and then releasing the reset bypasses this bootup and lets the ST-LINK interface control the STM.

Comment: No, I only have simple code turning on and off LED conneced to PC13. Nothing else. But can You tell me why st put special setup called "connect under reset". What ist it for?